# Get Context in Process.java

Tags: android

I want to get the package name of the app before killing app's pid. So that I need to modify killProcess(pid) of android/os/Process.java. How to do this since it does not have a Context? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a static class and extends `Application`, in that class, create a static variable for the Context. Use the variable along with and anywhere in your application. Try this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;
    private static Application application;

    public static Application getApplication(){
        return application;
    }

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
        MyApplication.application = getApplication();
 }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

Dont forget to declare the Custom Application in  at your manifest file:

```
<application
        android:name="your.package.MyApplication"
...>
...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

To kill an android process manually is a bad practice but you can use this line to kill that.

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

or

you can decleare a static variable in Main_activity and assign the application context here. Then you can access package name any where in applicaton

```
public static String packageName;
```

Then..

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    .
    .   
    packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
}
```

you can use this as `Main_activity.pacageName`